# Jenkins not accessible

Tags: ubuntu, networking, jenkins, raspberry-pi, apt-get

I have just installed Jenkins throught `sudo apt-get install jenkins`, the service is running however it is not accessible through the default port 8080.

```
    user@user-desktop:~$ sudo service jenkins status
● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since lø. 2017-03-11 19:00:34 CET; 22h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 7102 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/jenkins stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7139 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0

mars 11 19:00:32 user-desktop systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
mars 11 19:00:32 user-desktop jenkins[7139]:  * Starting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server jenkins
mars 11 19:00:33 user-desktop su[7177]: Successful su for jenkins by root
mars 11 19:00:33 user-desktop su[7177]: + ??? root:jenkins
mars 11 19:00:33 user-desktop su[7177]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
mars 11 19:00:34 user-desktop jenkins[7139]:    ...done.
mars 11 19:00:34 user-desktop systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
```

When I run `Netstat -tap`:

```
user@user-desktop:~$ netstat -tap
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 user-desktop:domain    *:*                     LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      -
tcp        0    240 192.168.1.221:ssh       192.168.1.34:49858      ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      -
```

I am not able to locate Jenkins running on port 8080, and I am not able to see any errors in the Jenkins log file.

I appriciate any tips for troubleshooting this problem.

EDIT: Syslog.

```
Mar 14 13:41:00 user-desktop systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of jenkins.
Mar 14 13:41:00 user-desktop systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 124...
Mar 14 13:41:01 user-desktop systemd[1]: Started Session c19 of user jenkins.
Mar 14 13:41:01 user-desktop systemd[23777]: Reached target Paths.
Mar 14 13:41:01 user-desktop systemd[23777]: Reached target Sockets.
Mar 14 13:41:01 user-desktop systemd[23777]: Reached target Timers.
Mar 14 13:41:01 user-desktop systemd[23777]: Reached target Basic System.
Mar 14 13:41:01 user-desktop systemd[23777]: Reached target Default.
Mar 14 13:41:01 user-desktop systemd[23777]: Startup finished in 80ms.
Mar 14 13:41:01 user-desktop systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 124.
Mar 14 13:41:02 user-desktop jenkins[23724]:    ...done.
Mar 14 13:41:02 user-desktop systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
Mar 14 13:41:10 user-desktop jenkins: Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
Mar 14 13:41:10 user-desktop jenkins:
```

Comment: In your service output you can see the state of service. `active (exited)` in this case means that jenkins is not running and something went wrong. Try to start your service and gather some informations from syslog to check what is going on. You can always try to manually start jenkins to see what is happening

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not able to locate any errors in the `syslog`, I have attached the log in the main post. Hopefully you are able to help me troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Find Jenkins user by this command:

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/jenkins | grep JENKINS_USER
```

Then set  permissions to the Jenkins user to the files and folders as follows:

```
chown -R jenkinsuser:jenkinsuser /var/lib/jenkins
chown -R jenkinsuser:jenkinsuser  /var/cache/jenkins
chown -R jenkinsuser:jenkinsuser  /var/log/jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

> As I was connected to my company's VPN, wasnt able to connect.
> Disconnected from VPN and it worked.  Even though my netstat -tulpn
> would give ipv6 connection, i was still able to connect through
> regular web explorer

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
                            -
```